# Android activity recognition issue

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intentservice, activity-recognition

I am developing android native applications. My requirement is to get the current activity of the device like running,in_vehicle,still and so on. I used ActivityRecognitionAPI and set the pendingintent to receive the activity changes through IntentService. I gave 5 seconds interval for each updated. Its failed to provide the activity changes in certain period of time and again started providing activity. After that i preferred Awareness SnapshotAPI to get the activity state. Its also same result, failed to provide the activity regularly. Both APIs sometimes providing and many times not. I used GooglePlayServices 10.2.0 version for my developemnt. Anyone tell what is the reason for these things and solution to get regular activity updates..

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to show my app user's activity like he is walking, running and so on. This is my requirement.

Way 1:

//Google API client using ActivityRecognition.API

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RequestActivityService.class);
PendingIntent callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 111,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(googleApiClient,5000, callbackIntent);

public class RequestActivityService extends IntentService {
public RequestActivityService() {
    super("RequestActivityService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {

            ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult
                    .extractResult(intent);

            DetectedActivity mostProbableActivity = result
                    .getMostProbableActivity();

            int confidence = mostProbableActivity.getConfidence();

            int activityType = mostProbableActivity.getType();
            String activityName = getNameFromType(activityType);

        }
}
```

** I tried this way to get activity updates. It started providing the activity info, but Intent service not called sometimes and again started firing the intent. So I am not able to show the correct activity information.

Way 2:

//Google API client using Awareness.API

```
Awareness.SnapshotApi.getDetectedActivity(googleApiClient).

                setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DetectedActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull DetectedActivityResult detectedActivityResult) {
                        if (!detectedActivityResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i("Could not get the activity","");
                            return;
                        }
                        ActivityRecognitionResult ar = detectedActivityResult.getActivityRecognitionResult();
                        DetectedActivity probableActivity = ar.getMostProbableActivity();
                        String activityType = RequestActivityService.getNameFromType(probableActivity.getType());
                        int activityConfidence = probableActivity.getConfidence();
                    }
                });
```

** I tried this another way, using this Api we can call this method recursively and get the activity information frequently. But Its also sometime providing and sometimes detectedActivityResult.getStatus() not success. If I am trying to get the status code and status message, status code returns 15 and status message will be null.

Both these ways are failed to give regular updates of activity and more over I used GooglePlayService 10.2.0 version. I have tested the GoogleSamples of ActivityRecognition from Github. That is also same result. I don't know what do to achieve my requirement. Hope now u can understand my requirement and things which I faced.

Comment: Please, be more specific about what you are trying to do and how? then what is the problem. It would be great and helpful if you include codes...

Comment: I am trying to show my app user's activity like he is walking, running and so on. This is my requirement.

Comment: So you are talking about user activity represented by Google Fit  not Activity class in Android. right ?

Comment: Yeah.. I am not talking about Activity class. Just see my edited post. I described about my requirement, code and the interruption which I faced.

Answer (score 0):

ActivityRecognitionAPI from Google doesn't give updates regularly. From what I have noticed, if there is a change in the confidence level of the activity or the activity changes altogether, then it'll send an update. Even then, it'll take time to ensure the data read isn't just noise of some kind.

I'm not sure why you need regular updates, but I would suggest changing the logic to accept the last given activity as the current activity, and only act upon the changes (i.e., `STILL` -> `IN_VEHICLE`).

Answer (score -1):

Call this method again after getting response:

I would suggest to set detectionIntervalMillis to 0. That will lead to get data ASAP.( be aware of battery consumption )

```
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(googleApiClient,o, callbackIntent);
```

Comment: I set getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); in my activity. Now I am getting regular updates without interruption or temporary stop.

Answer (score -1):

if there are no changes for long time, it will not send updates till change occur...